# ExtJS 4 - get button when store.load

Tags: extjs4

can you halp me to do something like this

```
{
    xtype : 'button',
    text  : 'Prikazi',
    handler : function(item,el){
       this.setDisabled(true);
       store.load(function(records, operation, success) {
           if(success){ this.up('button').setDisabled(false); }
       });
    }
}
```

problem: *this.up('button')*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the parameters that you're passing -

because 'this' refers first to the button and in the callback it refers to the store:

```
{
   xtype:  'button',
   text:   'Refresh',
   id:     'btn_refresh',
   handler: function(clicked_button, the_event) {

      clicked_button.setDisabled(true);

      store.load(function(records, operation, success) {
         if(success){
            clicked_button.setDisabled(false);
         }
      });

   }
}
```

Might be more elegant to use the store's beforeload event to control the button-state.

Update: changed variable names to make the example even more obvious.

Maybe checkout [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com) or [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) once

... and please accept the answer in case it should have been helpful.